# find file newer than yesterday using batch script

Tags: windows-xp, batch-file

I am trying to write a batch script that can find the files created/modified/newer since yesterday and/or any specific day from today in a particular folder. Then those files need to be copied to different location.

I tried to use the `forfiles` command but my XP doesn't have that command.

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: The utility `forfiles` is not included with Windows, it is from the Windows Server 2000 Resource Kit.  You can also download the executable itself from [the Petri site](http://www.petri.co.il/download_free_reskit_tools.htm).

Comment: If you're willing to install cygwin, you can use `find /cygdrive/c/your/folder -ctime 1 | xargs mv -t /cygdrive/c/new/folder` to perform all that (files changed within the last 24 hours; there are other time options if you need to be more precise).

Comment: hey kevin - thanks for this! even though i havent worked with cygwin and dont know what it is, i will give it a shot.

Comment: If installing something as extensive as cygwin is a possibility, you should look into using powershell as well.

Comment: hey scott - i tried to download the forfiles utility from the website you mentioned, installed it, but my xp computer still gives me 'not recognized command' error. any idea why?

Comment: hey scott - i got it. just so people like me knows, copy and paste the forfiles.exe in c:\...\system32 folder to make it work. thanks man, let me dig around since i can run forfiles and get back to you, if have any question... thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Horst Schaeffer's excellent [wasfile.exe](http://www.horstmuc.de/wbat32.htm#wasfile) tool:

`for /r c:\particular_folder %i in (*.*) do @wasfile.exe %i created after Today-1 > nul && @copy %i f:\different_location`

You can change **created** and **modified**  per your need:

```
WasFile, ver. 2.2 (c) 2006-2007, Horst Schaeffer
compares ..
    the time&date of two files (or directories),
    the date only, time ignored
    the date of a file with TODAY-n (days)
    the time&date of a file with NOW-n (minutes)
Examples:
    WasFile this.zip created before that.zip
    WasFile this.zip modified after today-8
Syntax:
    WasFile File1 [Stamp] [not] before|after|sametime File2 [Stamp] [Option]
    WasFile File1 [Stamp] [not] before|after|sametime today-n [Option]
    WasFile File1 [Stamp] [not] before|after|sametime now-n
Stamp is either:
    created, modified (default) or accessed
    (by default second stamp = first stamp)
Options to compare date only, ignore time:
    /DateLocal or /DateUTC
    (if TODAY is used, default is /DateLocal)
Result by errorlevel:
    0: true, 1: false, 255: error (message to STDERR)
```

> by the way when you put (.), does it mean look for any format/kind of
>   the file? can i just put *.csv instead to search csv file only?

I think you mean (*.*)? Yes, this tells you what set you are interested in. *.csv would isolate just the csv files.

> also why are you using @wasfile.exe, nul, @ copy and switch %i (two
>   places)

You  might benefit from reading some web sites for background:
http://www.netikka.net/tsneti/http/tsnetihttpprog.php#batch
http://www.netikka.net/tsneti/info/tscmd.php

Google *batch tutorial* for more sites.

In a batch file, **@command**  means don't echo the command line to the screen. Otherwise, you will see both what you asked for as well as what the result was.
The **&&** means 'process what follows if command is successful' and determines this by [errorlevel](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/errorlevel.php). If I wanted 'was not successful' I would have used **||**.

In this case, you read the code as: Is the file newer than my target date, and if yes (&&) copy it to some location.  Don't show me any output from my command ">nul"
 Ok?

Comment: thank you very much rob! i will give it a shot. by the way when you put (*.*), does it mean look for any format/kind of the file? can i just put *.csv instead to search csv file only? also why are you using @wasfile.exe, nul, @ copy and switch %i (two places)?

Comment: I'll append my answer to my post above

Answer (score 0):

This is easily achievable using VBScript, with its GetFile() and DateDiff() functions.  VBScript is native to XP.

```
Option Explicit
On Error Resume Next
Err.Clear

processFolder "c:\temp"

WScript.Quit


Function processFolder( strPath )

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim objFSO
    Dim objFolder
    Dim intRc
    Dim colFiles
    Dim objFile

    intRc = 0

    Set objFSO = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        intRc = -1
        Err.Clear
    Else

        Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder( strPath )
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            intRc = -2
            Err.Clear
        Else

            Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                intRc = -3
                Err.Clear
            Else

                For Each objFile in colFiles
                    checkFile strPath, objFile.Name, (24 * 60 * 60)
                Next

                Set colFiles = Nothing
            End If

            Set objFolder = Nothing

        End If

        Set objFSO = Nothing
    End If

processFolder = intRc

End Function



Function checkFile( ByVal strPath, strName, intThreshold )

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim objFSO
    Dim objFile
    Dim intRc
    Dim strFileName
    Dim intModificationPeriodSecs
    Dim objDateLastModified

    intRc = 0
    strFileName = strPath & "\" & strName

    Set objFSO = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        intRc = -1
        Err.Clear
    Else

        Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile( strFileName )
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            intRc = -2
            Err.Clear
        Else

            'intRc = objFile.Size
            objDateLastModified = objFile.DateLastModified
            intModificationPeriodSecs = DateDiff( "s", objDateLastModified, Now )

            If intModificationPeriodSecs > intThreshold Then
                WScript.Echo "File [" & strFileName & "] last modified [" & intModificationPeriodSecs & "] seconds ago."
            End If

            Set objFile = Nothing

        End If

        Set objFSO = Nothing
    End If

checkFile = intRc

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
forfiles /P C:\someDirectory /S /D -1
```

found [here](https://www.windows-commandline.com/find-files-based-on-modified-time/).
Quite fast.